# what is * arguments (without suffix) function/method in python?

Tags: python

I recently worked on several projects and see a new syntax code, a method that get a * arguments(i know about *args and **kwargs)

for an example in django 2.0.4:

```
class DataListView(ListView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs): # * argument without suffix
        return super().get_context_data(object_list, **kwargs)
```

and **Question**: what is meaning of * arguments in python function/method?

Answer (score 3):

It's so that `object_list` must be a named argument. All positional arguments will be captured by `*` and ignored.

This was added in python 3.0 and is described in [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Comment: can you share any document for this?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to the relevant PEP.